# Parent directive controller undefined when passing to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I asked general question here in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814530/pass-argument-between-parent-and-child-directives). I've got answer with working example; however when I try to use this example to modify existing code, I get error.
See my code below and in this [Plunker page](https://plnkr.co/edit/IYqjYtx2RcHSz06XgGoT?p=preview).

Html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <tmp-menu ng-disabled="true">
    <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
    <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
  </tmp-menu>
</div>
```

JavaScript(AngularJS):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyDirectiveController', MyDirectiveController)
.directive('tmpMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
      disabled: '=?ngDisabled'
    },
    controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
    template: '<div>myDirective Disabled: {{ disabled }}<ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


    }
  };
})
.directive('tmpMenuLink', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
    },
    required:'^^tmpMenu',
    template: '<div>childDirective disabled: {{ disabled }}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, MyDirectiveCtrl) {
      console.log(MyDirectiveCtrl);

      scope.disabled = MyDirectiveCtrl.isDisabled();

    }
  };
})

function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
  this.isDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.disabled;
  };
}
```

Inside directive ***tmpMenuLink***, **MyDirectiveCtrl** is *undefined*.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
required:'^^tmpMenu',
```

change it to

```
require:'^^tmpMenu',
```

Check this plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/DgyW3OFgr1GyAR8fuATi?p=preview

Comment: added follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128652/child-directive-not-updated-when-parent-directive-property-changes

Answer (score 1):

Because it's `require` not `required`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyDirectiveController', MyDirectiveController)
  .directive('tmpMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        disabled: '=?ngDisabled'
      },
      controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
      template: '<div>myDirective Disabled: {{ disabled }}<ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    };
  })
  .directive('tmpMenuLink', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      require: '^^tmpMenu',
      template: '<div>childDirective disabled: {{ disabled }}</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, MyDirectiveController) {

        scope.disabled = MyDirectiveController.isDisabled();

      }
    };
  })

function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
  this.isDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.disabled;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <tmp-menu ng-disabled="true">
    <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
    <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
  </tmp-menu>
</div>
```