# Child directive not updated when parent directive property changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is follow up to these 2 questions:

1. [Pass argument between parent and child directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814530/pass-argument-between-parent-and-child-directives)
2. [Parent directive controller undefined when passing to child directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986855/parent-directive-controller-undefined-when-passing-to-child-directive)

I have this part working; however, when the value for ng-disabled for parent directive changes, the child directive values don't get updated.

Please see thin [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QCgOrdn28mRoyfFTiOWN?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    {{menuStatus}}
    <tmp-menu ng-disabled="menuStatus">
      <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
      <tmp-menu-link></tmp-menu-link>
    </tmp-menu>
    <button ng-click="updateStatus()">Update</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript(AngularJS):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyDirectiveController', MyDirectiveController)
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.menuStatus = false;
  $scope.updateStatus = function(){
    $scope.menuStatus = $scope.menuStatus?false:true;
  }
})
.directive('tmpMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
      disabled: '=?ngDisabled'
    },
    controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
    template: '<div>myDirective Disabled: {{ disabled }}<ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


    }
  };
})
.directive('tmpMenuLink', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope:{
    },
    require:'^^tmpMenu',
    template: '<div>childDirective disabled: {{ disabled }}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, MyDirectiveCtrl) {
      console.log(MyDirectiveCtrl);

      scope.disabled = MyDirectiveCtrl.isDisabled();

    }
  };
})

function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
  this.isDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.disabled;
  };
}
```

How can I detect change in parent directive and pass it to child directive without adding angular watcher.

Comment: you should have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482.  It has **a lot** of information that will explain what is going on here;  this is one of the most common issues for new angular developers, and is the reason there is a rule:  **always use a dot in angular bindings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

i've set up a working plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fsxMJPAc05imhBqefaRk?p=preview

the reason of this behaviour is that `tmpMenuLink` kept a copy of the value returned from `MyDirectiveCtrl.isDisabled()`. no watcher is set up , so the only way to resolve this is to manually watch for any changes and then update the field.

```
scope.$watch(function(){
  return MyDirectiveCtrl.isDisabled();
}, function(){
   scope.disabled = MyDirectiveCtrl.isDisabled();
})
```

**Solution 2**

An alternative without watchers is to pass the reference of an object instead of a primitive type, something like:

```
$scope.menuStatus = {status: false};
```

new plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RGEK6TUuE7gkPDS6ygZe?p=preview

Comment: If I set this watcher in tmpMenuLink directive, and, let's say I have 20 links, will I have 20 watchers running all the time?

Comment: yes. i've just added a new solution without watchers

Comment: Hi your new plunker looks similar to the old one, it has watchers.

Comment: Solution 2 is what I was looking for. I was playing with passing object instead of simple value and I found that $attrs gets updated every time and passed to controller. Look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MMgfD4fukb5VAVrtwLF6?p=preview

Comment: nice. glad i could help you :)